# how does chef gets instance ids of aws ec2 when we dont mention node name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

if I gave --node-name option in my knife ec2 server create node name is taking

> for e.g:

```
 knife ec2 server create -r "role[test]" -I ami-59aas30 --flavor
 t1.micro -x ubuntu --ssh-key VS_Key --availability-zone us-east-1a -p
 22 --tags Name=filetext --subnet subnet-f7sdfdf -g sg-8adsf3e4
 --node-name Testnode
```

my question is if I don't mention any node name how it is taking the instance-id as node name, I want to use instance ids in my code. I would like to know, how it is taking the instance's ids

Answer (score 2):

On ubuntu you can use ec2metadata, which is part of the cloud-utils apt-get package:

apt-get install cloud-utils

ec2metadata --instance-id

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify Amazon EC2 instance IDs - EC2 generates those values for you when you create a new virtual machine. The `--node-name` flag corresponds to the node's name **in the Chef Server**, not the instance id.

To get the id for a specific instance, you can use the [AWS Command Line Tools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeInstances.html):

```
ec2-describe-instances
```

Or you can use `knife`:

```
knife ec2 server list
```

Or you can search the node attributes for this value:

```
knife search node "node_name:YOURNAME" -a ec2.instance_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the instance-id from [instance identity document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-identity-documents.html)

```
instance_info = 
  Chef::HTTP.new('http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document').get('/')
instance_id = JSON.parse(instance_info)['instanceId']
```

`169.254.169.254` is the IP of Amazon's service that serves these documents so this should work as long as you run it from your machine running on AWS.